# Elasticsearch: running commands in Windows prompt and 'pretty' causes error

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning Elasticsearch and I run the following in Windows prompt:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/test-index/_search?size=0&pretty -d @executing_an_aggregation.json
```

This is the content of executing_an_aggregation.json

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "tag": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "tag",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I got the following:

{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":980,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]}}'pretty' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Note that 'pretty' is causing errors. How can I get pretty results in Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `pretty=true`?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I am using Elasticsearch Cookbook to learn Elasticsearch and the commands I used were copied from this book.

Comment: looks like a commandline issue - and has nothing to do with elastic search. Try to escape the URL -> `curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test-index/_search?size=0&pretty' -d @executing_an_aggregation.json`. If that does not help look into the curl syntax (probably depends on your environment - could be `curl -help`)

Comment: After using 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test-index/_search?size=0&pretty', I got this error: curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl 'pretty'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double-quotes, instead of simple ones. In the definitive guide everything has been tested in Unix-live environment.

```
curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:9200/blog/_search?size=0&pretty" -d @executing_an_aggregation.json
```

Comment: How to pass full path of file?